# How to quickly assign keyboard shortcuts to launch your favorite applications using autohotkey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

In Windows (XP, 7, 8) how do you quickly assign keyboard shortcuts to launch your favorite applications using autohotkey when the application is active.

In Keyboard utilities, you can launch your favorite applications for fast access, by simply pressing a hotkey.

I was wandering if that could be done using autohotkey as well.

**Edited:**

Normally to add a script that when `Ctrl+Alt+N` is pressed, Notepad will be launched. You would need to have the following script.

> ^!n:: Run Notepad

What I want is that when the application is active, pressing `Ctrl + Shift + A` should take the path where the application is installed and create a script like above.

So when Command Prompt is active, pressing `Ctrl + Shift + A`  should create a script like the following.

> ^!t:: Run C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

where **C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe** is the **path** where **cmd** is **installed/located**

and  `Ctrl + Shift + T` is the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Yes, it is windows (XP, 7, 8)

Comment: Added it to the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you can do easily.

You could do something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851677/dynamically-create-autohotkey-hotkey-to-function-subroutine

Or you could modify your file at runtime and reload it.

```
#SingleInstance Force
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

^!n::
    WinGet, pn, ProcessName, A
    path := GetProcessPath(pn)
    tooltip, press a new hotkey
    Input, new_hotkey, L1
    tooltip,

    code = ^!%new_hotkey%`:`:Run, %path%`n
    FileAppend, %code%, %A_ScriptFullPath%

    Reload
    Sleep 1000 ; If successful, the reload will close this instance during the Sleep, so the line below will never be reached.
    MsgBox, 4,, The script could not be reloaded. Would you like to open it for editing?
    IfMsgBox, Yes, Edit
    return


GetProcessPath(exe) {
    ;;http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/32965-getting-file-path-of-a-running-process/
    for process in ComObjGet("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process where name ='" exe "'")
        return process.ExecutablePath
}

return

Hotkeys:
^!f::Run, C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The following example will launch explorer when Win+0 is pressed (# denotes the Window key in AHK):

`#0::Run C:\Windows\System32\explorer.exe`

If the application does not launch because it is already running, you could create a batch file containing:

`start program.exe`

And tell the AHK script to launch that batch file.

Comment: I already knew how to do that but this is not what I am after. Your solution requires to actually find the application path and then create a keyboard shortcuts from it. Please have a look at the http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzcQbrkdvJU&feature=player_embedded
 to illustrate what I am after but using autohotkey instead of PhraseExpander which the video uses.

Comment: So you're after a GUI to create shortcut assignments?

Answer (score 0):

To quickly assign keyboard shortcuts to launch my favorite applications, I created an AutoHotkey script very easy to use and configure that allow to Open, Minimize or Restore a Window App, a Chrome App or a Chrome shortcut. 
It also has some other features like Error catching etc..  the code is here:
https://github.com/JuanmaMenendez/AutoHotkey-script-Open-Show-Apps

**Configuration Examples**

```
F7:: OpenOrShowAppBasedOnExeName("C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe")

F8:: OpenOrShowAppBasedOnWindowTitle("Gmail", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --app=https://mail.google.com/mail/")
```

I hope you found it helpful ;) ‍♂️⭐